# I can't get a service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is described in the next code:

```
var eventModule = angular.module('eventModule', ['ngResource']);

eventModule.factory('Event', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('http://cip-cirip.ro/API/events/:eventId', {}, {
          query: {method:'GET', params:{eventId:'55'}, isArray:false}
        });
    }
]);

eventModule.controller('events_interface', function ($scope, $http){
    //$scope.events = [{id:1, name:'evenimentul 1'},{id:2, name:'evenimentul 2'}];
    var ev = Event();
    console.log(ev);
    $scope.events = ev.query();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the service as dependency wherever you need to access it:

```
eventModule.controller('events_interface', function ($scope, $http, Event){...
```

Comment: var eventModule = angular.module('eventModule', ['ngResource']);

eventModule.factory('Event', ['$resource',
 function($resource){
  return $resource('http://cip-cirip.ro/API/events/', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
  });
 }
]);

eventModule.controller('events_interface', function ($scope, $http, Event){
 //$scope.events = [{id:1, name:'evenimentul 1'},{id:2, name:'evenimentul 2'}];
 var ev = new Event();
 console.log(ev);
 $scope.events = [];
 $scope.events = ev.$query();
});

Comment: @AdrianB there's a very obvious syntax error `;` in your `$resource` parameters.